# Delete Swipe gestures in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to create an ionic delete swipe gesture but it doesn't seem to work.

```
**This is my home page ( i called it myPage.html)**
    <ion-header>
      <ion-navbar color="secondary">
        <ion-title align="center">
          My Tasks
        </ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
          <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addItem()"><ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-navbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="viewItem(item)">{{item.title}}</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>

    <ion-item-sliding (ionSwipe)="delete(item)">
      <ion-item>Item</ion-item>
      <ion-item-options>
        <button ion-button expandable (click)="delete(item)">Delete</button>
      </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>

    <ion-footer>
      <ion-toolbar >
        <ion-title>@2018, MyBlog | by SRM </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-footer>
```

I did follow the documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemSliding/ but I think I'm missing something and I'm still new to this. Can anyone please help me? :(

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs, you need to put the `ion-item` inside `ion-item-sliding` component.

Thus, the structure of your markup should be:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ion-item>
            {{item.title}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="right">
            <button ion-button (click)="delete(item)">
                <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>Delete
            </button>
        </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

Refer here for the sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-eofb82

Comment: @Adrian- Thank you so much it works! how about the edit? is it using the same code as delete?

Comment: @HannaNanna, yes it's the same, you just need to add another button and put in a edit function in the click event.

Comment: @Adrian- I did create a new button using the same code.. but it doesnt work. like im going to edit it in modal view.

Comment: <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ion-item>
            {{item.title}}
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options side="right">
            <button ion-button (click)="delete(item)">
                <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>Delete
            </button> <button ion-button (click)="edit(item)">
                <ion-icon name="copy"></ion-icon>Edit
            </button>
        </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list> (For html)

Comment: @Adrian- this is the .ts page edit(item){
 
    let editModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddItemPage);
 
    editModal.onDidDismiss((item) => {
 
          if(item){
            this.saveItem(item);
          }
 
    });
 
    editModal.present();
 
  }

Comment: You should add it in a running app like in stackblitz I posted above so that we can see it in action and what error occurred.