# How to create notification list Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, swipe, hybrid-mobile-app, drag

I need to create a drag option like left to right **(Swipe)**. If I did right to left need to close that card. But I'm not sure how to do it in **ionic 4**.

modal popup should be open like popup from the bottom, **but not popup**.

Can anyone help me with this modal?.

Comment: Check this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item-sliding

Comment: yeah, it's sliding but I need like swipe (When I need to clear that should swipe right to left)

Comment: You want swipe right to delete it?

Comment: yeah, exactly right

Comment: can you suggest to me any popup(Template) for filer panel like popup without cancel option?.

Comment: Check Ionic Swipe Gestures: https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/gestures

Comment: Check this for Popover Options: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#select-buttons  you can remove buttons.

Comment: Gestures only allow track, I seen somewhere swipe delete notifications

Comment: thanks for your help, I found I need as this will fix 
https://codepen.io/MichalFoksa/pen/qaNKdP

Comment: finally, I found that that is sliding https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-eofb82?file=app%2Fapp.html

Comment: I found the answer, Please check here what I required.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49037457/delete-swipe-gestures-in-ionic-3

Comment: Thats what I was proposing...